# Unable to shutdown, shutting down process stuck

Tags: shutdown

[image: blank desktop screenshot]

I am not able to shut down Ubuntu 16.04. The shutting down process is stuck. Please advice on how to proceed.

Comment: Can you open terminal using Ctrl+Alt+T or Ctrl+Alt+F1?

Comment: @Melebius I tried opening the terminal using the key combinations you mentioned but I am not able to open.

Comment: @Melebius: I tried opening the terminal using the key combinations you mentioned but I am not able to open.

Answer (score 2):

I saw that you are using VirtualBox.

Try to send reboot command from VirtualBox.

Comment: by reboot you mean reset command ?

Comment: the reset option helped

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and type

> reboot

I think it will work on your computer.

Comment: Could you please advice how to open terminal ? I tried opening using Ctrl+Alt+T or Ctrl+Alt+F1 but I am not able to open.